# Properties file location in Strtus2

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, localization, internationalization

I am using Struts2 in my application. I have a `MessageResources.properties` where all the keys and values are given. This file is in the location `${tomcat_home}/properties/resources`. My question is how can I provide this file location in `struts.xml`? In `struts.xml` I've tried giving

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="/usr/local/tomcat/properties/resources/MessageResources"/>
```

But this is not working. The properties are not being retrieved.

Comment: Why do you want to load properties from the outside of the classpath?

Comment: because 2 of my war files are using the same resources files.

Answer (score 2):

Struts2 loads properties from the classpath. Put your properties files in the `src` or `resources` folder under the given package.

If the package name is `com.example.resources` then you should use

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="/com/example/resources/MessageResources"/>
```

Comment: I need to put the resources in tomcat folder, as 2 of my war files are using the same resources files. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: It's possible, but it's not recommended way to do so.

Comment: so, if i am giving the resources in tomcat folder, as i mentioned in the question, how can the path be given in strtus.xml?

Comment: you have to use a relative path from the classpath.

Comment: i have put the resources in `tomcat/properties/resources/myproj`. i added properties folder in classpath and in `struts.xml` gave `resources.myproj.MessageResources`. but its also not working

Comment: not working in the sense, the resources are not being picked from the bundle. the keys are displayed in the UI rather than value

Comment: resources should be in right place to be loaded, otherwise it won't load.